# Transform month abbreviation strings to date in python

Tags: python, date-formatting

I have a list with abbreviated month names

```
shortmonth = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

And I want to make each element as a date format in year 2020, so each element will be in the form of

```
'2020-01-01'
```

As a date and not a simple string. I am very new to python, if anyone could explain me how to do this.

Comment: As in `2020-XX-01` for each element?

Comment: yes, each one to be in that format and only the month to be changed

Comment: Are you planning on using `datetime.datetime` objects for your dates?

Comment: yes I would like to be able to do that too

Comment: If the list in `shortmonth` is really just all months in order, there are probably simpler solutions where you just use the numbers 1 to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range()` to generate the month numbers; the `shortmonth` list is not necessary. You can do the following:

```py
print(['2020-{0:02d}-01'.format(i) for i in range(1, 13)])
```

If you want to create `datetime` objects, you can do the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print([datetime.strptime('2020-{0:02d}-01'.format(i), "%Y-%m-%d") for i in range(1, 13)])
```

Comment: This only works if the months in `shortmonth` are really just all the months of the year.

Comment: I'm assuming OP thought that the list was necessary to generate the dates, which it isn't. You could argue that one may at some point need to handle subsets of elements in `shortmonth`, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: that's right, I thought the list had to be necessary

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date` objects, and assuming you want all the months in order, you can skip the month abbreviation strings and do something like:

```
month_starts = [
    datetime.date(year=2020, month=month, day=1)
    for month in range(1, 13)
]
```

or

```
month_starts = [
    datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=month, day=1)
    for month in range(1, 13)
]
```

If you do need to work with the month abbreviation strings, you can do something like:

```
month_abbr = 'Apr'  # coming from a file, input or from elsewhere in the program

month_number = shortmonth.index(month_abbr) + 1
the_month_start = datetime.date(year=2020, month=month_number, day=1)
```